# Connect Ftp Via PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have to connect to moteng site ftp. I have tried with below code but i'm not getting connected.

```
$ftp_server="ftp://dropbox.moteng.com/";
$ftp_user_name="xxxx";
$ftp_pass="xxxx";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_pass);
```

Here login result is null.

But same login details working in browser.

Please help to complete this task. thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$conn_id` - if it's `FALSE`, the connection failed. Same goes for `$login_result`.

Answer (score 4):

Directly from the manual:

`The FTP server address. This parameter shouldn't have any trailing slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://.`

You made both mistakes, having a trailing slash, and prefixing it with `ftp://`

Comment: i have tried with out ftp://. but again it's not getting connected. I used same login in browser but it's working.

Now  $server = "dropbox.moteng.com";

Comment: It's working. thanks.. I did some mistake in code. Thanks :-)